# How to install LibreOffice on Bodhi Linux

Tags: libreoffice, bodhi

How to install the LibreOffice suit on the latest Bodhi Linux version (4.5.0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install it from [the LibreOffice page in the AppCenter](http://www.bodhilinux.com/a/libre-office/) by clicking on the “Install” button.

Answer (score 0):

@Stephen Kitt's answer works.
This is its equivalent in command line, if you would prefer:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```